# How to use styles in ProgressIndicator from fluentui-react

Tags: fluentui-react

There is a property 'styles' that takes a

```
"IStyleFunctionOrObject<IProgressIndicatorStyleProps, IProgressIndicatorStyles>"
```

but I have no idea how to set it.
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styles` prop can be a `function` or `object`

What you can customize:

```
root: IStyle;
itemName: IStyle;
itemDescription: IStyle;
itemProgress: IStyle;
progressTrack: IStyle;
progressBar: IStyle;
```

Modify `background-color` of progress bar:

```
<ProgressIndicator
  ...
  styles={{
    progressBar: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
    }
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/jOBWmrK)

Comment: Thank you. Itried progressBar: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00', height:'200px'
    } but it did not make the line thicker.

Comment: You need to change `root` property to `height: 200px`, then do the same for `progressBar`, `progressTrack` and `itemProgress`. See Codepen example.

Comment: @OferGal Can you mark answer as correct if that's the solution you are looking for? Thank you.